# Does space matter in Jinja?

Tags: python, jinja2

What David has written in CS50 2022 - Lecture 9 - Flask, layout.html is

```
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

What I typically do in Django, a similar Python web framework is

```
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

Does space matter in Jinja? Is it a matter of style? Because I know HTML is also space insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe spaces are important. Just there are replicated in the rendered template.

In template components most included, many spaces in the component can create many spaces in the rendered html that you will send to web client. I use the `{% spaceless %}{% endspaceless %}` for removing them in django template language.

In Jinja, you can set trim_blocks and lstrip_blocks on the env.

```
app.jinja_env.trim_blocks = True
app.jinja_env.lstrip_blocks = True
```

You can also use `-` for removing spaces in conditional block:

```
{%- if ... -%} --> strips before and after
```

You can use `+` for be sure to preserve space in same way.